# PowerApps - Allow multiple forms to be edited at once

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-modeldriven

I am currently building a model driven app through Microsoft PowerApps. The app will service a lab where lab techs can enter the results of their tests on production samples into the the form as they are occurring. One form will contain the results for one test.
The issue I keep running into is that the lab techs will often be conducting tests on 4-5 samples at once, and would like to be able to have 4-5 forms open at one time in order to prevent from having to save and close a previous form and open a new form for each sample.
I know there is no default solution for this, but has anyone had experience with a solution like this before and can something be designed to allow the lab techs to have several forms open at one time where they can enter results quickly across each of them?